# HTML Form arguments to angular page

Tags: html, angularjs, forms

I have a static HTML page with a form on it asking for very basic information (Name, email).
This form will help pre-fill 2 fields of the registration process of my angular app.

the problem is that the URL that is being generated when submitting the form is
`http://server/?name=xxx&email=xxx@yyy.com/#/account/create/infos`

What my angular app is expecting is :
`http://server/#/account/create/infos/?name=xxx&email=xxx@yyy.com`

any idea how I can achieve that ?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

you can try setup your form to method post

> `<form method="post">...`

Then in controller you get post-param and process it